# SQLite order of operations in a query

Tags: sqlite, user-defined-functions

I have a query of the form:

```
SELECT akey, avalue, expensiveop(akey) FROM atable WHERE avalue < SOME_CONSTANT;
```

It appears that expensiveop()--which is a user-defined function that takes a fair amount of time to execute--gets called for all rows in the table.  For performance reasons I only want it to execute once for each row in the result set.

I tried the following approach, which did not seem to make a difference:

```
SELECT akey, avalue, expensiveop(akey) FROM (SELECT * FROM atable WHERE avalue < SOME_CONSTANT)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See *9.0 Subquery flattening* at http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html (and search for CROSS JOIN at the same page for ideas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read about SQLite's optimizer at this page, especially the Subquery flattening part:
http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#flattening

It contains a list of 19 conditions all of which must be met to allow subquery flattening to happen. Choose one, and do the exact oppposite it says, for example some random examples (untested):

```
 SELECT akey, avalue, expensiveop(akey)
 FROM (SELECT * FROM atable WHERE avalue < SOME_CONSTANT LIMIT 99999999)
 LIMIT 99999999

 SELECT akey, avalue, expensiveop(akey) FROM
(SELECT * FROM atable WHERE avalue < SOME_CONSTANT
 UNION
 SELECT * FROM atable WHERE 0 GROUP BY avalue)

 SELECT akey, avalue, expensiveop(akey) FROM
(SELECT * FROM atable WHERE avalue < SOME_CONSTANT LIMIT -1 OFFSET 0)
```

Comment: I like the 3rd one, but I think the syntax is invalid.  I think the end of the subquery needs to be "LIMIT -1 OFFSET 0"

Comment: indeed, OFFSET requires LIMIT: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html I don't know if SQLite optimizes out no limit + offset 0 or not.

Comment: It appears to have the effect that I'm looking for, at least in 3.7.9.  I could see that changing in the future, however.

Comment: If nothing helps, then you might send a bug report to sqlite: http://www.sqlite.org/src/wiki?name=Bug+Reports , maybe they can give you a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

An idea for a workaround:

```
SELECT akey, avalue, CASE avalue < SOME_CONSTANT WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE expensiveop(akey) END FROM avalue WHERE avalue < SOME_CONSTANT
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is:

```
SELECT akey, avalue, expensiveop(akey)
FROM atable
WHERE avalue < SOME_CONSTANT
group by akey, avalue
```

SQL should execute the `where` and `group by` *before* doing the expensive operation, because it is using the aggregated "akey".  If the query had something like `min(expensiveop(akey))` then it would be performing it for every row.